# why I have not staged changes in git

Tags: git

Sometime (quite often actually) I found after a pull I will have some not staged changes in the working directory. Don't know why exact they are there cause I have certainly not edit any of them.

A diff cannot show any difference on those file, And to make thing more strange, they just don't go away even if I use `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git checkout -- <file>`.

Can anyone explain why and how I can get rid of them without commit it? I suspect it is related to the line-ending issue, but cannot confirm with it.

The following is what I did:

After pull, I do a `git status`, it shows:

```
# On branch mavenize
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   build/build.sh
#       modified:   build/ibuild.sh
```

Then I do a `git reset --hard HEAD`, it shows:

```
HEAD is now at b2d707e add maven pom
```

And then `git status`, it shows the same result as before.

I'm using windows, in .gitconfig,  autocrlf is set to "true"

Comment: You have newline issues.

Comment: Only if you can show some concrete example, we can help you pinpoint where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Slaks, can you elaborate it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Globally, you can use `git config --global core.autocrlf input`, and, on a per-repository basis, there is the [text attribute](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking-out_and_checking-in), whose values you can discern at the link above, but in summary text=auto is a good default option.